# Aren't the virtual work/virtual power principles in mechanics simply solving for the vector differential equation of motion in a preferred direction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, work, coordinate-systems, constrained-dynamics

My conceptual understanding of the virtual work/virtual power principles is that, by hypothesizing "virtual displacements"/"virtual velocities", one can solve the equations of motion of a system more readily by ignoring those unknowns which are not of interest. The key is to take these virtual displacements/virtual velocities in a way that the virtual work/virtual power done by them is evidently zero, thereby saving computational time. An obvious way to achieve this is to choose virtual displacements/velocities that are orthogonal to those forces which can be ignored.

My question is: isn't this just a fancy way of solving Newton's Second Law in a vector basis whose basis vectors are orthogonal to those unknowns that aren't of interest?

Most textbooks attach special meaning to the dot product that is performed between the sum of the forces and the "d'Alembert inertial forces" and the $\delta$ something that is usually introduced --- it might be a virtual displacement, it might be a virtual velocity. In the first case, the dot product is then interpreted as a virtual work. In the second, as a virtual power. However, can't this be entirely done without, and the dot product be interpreted as simply the projection of the forces/accelerations along a favorable direction along which it is obvious those unknowns that aren't of interest have no component? Or am I missing some key insights/advantages of specifically taking the "virtual" path of reasoning?